# Unit testing that code runs without exception in ScalaTest

Tags: scala, scalatest

TL;DR I have a Task[Unit], in ScalaTest/FlatSpec what is the proper way to test if the task succeeded in a given time frame?

I have an application with a server-client architecture, the interaction between client and server is non blocking.  This is implemented by calls on the client returning a future which completes when the server has finished the work.  Importantly this future does not return back the result, it is just used to indicate that the server has finished:

```
val notification: Task[Unit] = myServer.alterState("do this")
Await.result(notification.runAsync, 20.seconds)
```

What I want to test here is that the server is correctly sending notifications of completion to the client.  I'm testing this with FlatSpec from ScalaTest, and to me it seems that the following should be a valid test:

```
"Server" should "notify client upon completion" in {
    val notification: Task[Unit] = myServer.alterState("do this")
    Await.result(notification.runAsync, 20.seconds)
}
```

If the server takes longer than 20 seconds to reply, Await.result will throw an exception, which the test will catch, and fail.

Is this the correct way to perform this sort of test in flatspec?  All of the matching framework seems to be geared around testing the value of results, and catching expected exceptions, but I don't have a result returned, I just want to test that the future ends successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ScalaFutures`](http://doc.scalatest.org/3.0.1-2.12/org/scalatest/concurrent/ScalaFutures.html) enable to assert a `Future` is ready within a a specified time period like so

```
import org.scalatest._
import org.scalatest.concurrent.ScalaFutures
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

class ServerSpec extends FlatSpec with ScalaFutures {
  "Server" should "notify client upon completion" in {
    val notification: Task[Unit] = myServer.alterState("do this")
    assert(notification.runAsync.isReadyWithin(20 seconds))
  }
}
```

[AsyncFlatSpec](http://doc.scalatest.org/3.0.1-2.12/org/scalatest/AsyncFlatSpec.html) allows for idiomatic Scala syntax where we can map over `Future` like so

```
import org.scalatest._

class ServerSpec extends AsyncFlatSpec {
  "Server" should "notify client upon completion" in {
    val notification: Task[Unit] = myServer.alterState("do this")
    notification.runAsync.map(_ => succeed)
  }
}
```

but make sure server is designed to timeout, otherwise test will hang.

`FlatSpec` with `Await` could assert explicitly [no exception](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34645055/5205022) should be thrown like so

```
import org.scalatest._
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.duration._

class ServerSpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers {
  "Server" should "notify client upon completion" in {
    val notification: Task[Unit] = myServer.alterState("do this")
    noException should be thrownBy Await.result(notification.runAsync, 20.seconds)
  }
}
```

Personally, I would recommend `AsyncFlatSpec` method.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `intercept` method to verify the exception is thrown.

```
 val notification: Task[Unit] = myServer.alterState("do this")
 notification onComplete {
   case Failure(_) => fail()
   case Success(_) => succeed
 }
 intercept[TimeoutException] { //you can also use Exception instead of TimeoutException
   Await.result(notification.runAsync, 20.seconds)
  }
```

> If your code throws the exception, intercept catches it, and the test
>   succeeds. (You expected it to throw an exception, and it did.)

More details can be found [here](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_assertions)  or [here](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/scalatest-testing-expected-exceptions-intercept-testfailedexception)

Comment: This is the opposite of what I'm asking.  If the code works, my test is expecting no exceptions, so it shouldn't need to intercept one.  Basically the test is, did the code run without exceptions, did the task succeed?

Comment: Since you are not returning any result inside the future, all you need to know is that the future was executed within 20 seconds right?

Comment: Yes, or if the what executed inside the future threw an exception.  E.g. if the server encounters an error and cannot complete the task.

Comment: I updated my answer so the test would fail if there is a failure during the task execution. You still need the interception to catch cases that take longer than 20 seconds

Comment: Wouldn't that pass if the future times out though?  If intercept handles the timeout exception, then timeouts are treated as success right?

Comment: no. the purpose of the intercept is to make the test fail if the future times out. check the sources I provided